# how to decipher the coloured lines and nodes in the visual graph of the Git Gui Fork app?

Tags: git, user-interface, graph, colors

I would like to decipher the coloured lines and nodes in the git visual graph in the Fork Git Gui app clearly.Specifically as to what the different coloured lines signify??

I tried checking out the documentation and resources but did not find anything helpful.Just a few vague answers which were not in detail.

Comment: What software exactly? Please provide a screenshot.  Assuming this question is for the commercial software available at `git-fork.com`, it seems to be subtly mentioned here: https://git-fork.com/blog/posts/ (search for "color").  Since this question is not (directly) about programming, however, it's likely to be closed, since it's best asked to the support channels of the respective applications.  If this UI is common among non-proprietary apps as well, it would be helpful to update the question to describe that.

Comment: With regards specifically to the lines/nodes/colors, they appear to indicate different branches.  Regarding a color's significance, it's more likely that its position is more indicative than its color, as varying git GUI clients use different colors to represent (for example `master`) branches.  https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis